# Why is each String being written to a different file?

Tags: vb.net, loops, visual-studio-2012, file-io, system

I am trying to generate a size-based list of files. The current size being passed is 10 MB worth of file-names per text file. Instead of it counting to 10 MB and then incrementing the version letter, it is writing each file-name to its own individual file. This is strange as each file is ~150 kb, but I cannot figure out why it is reporting total as > number every time the code loops.

```
Private Function GenerateListsForSize(source As String, destination As String, name As String, number As Integer)
    Dim files As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim version As Char = "A"
    Dim path As String
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim passTexts As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo

    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(source)
        files.Add(foundFile)
    Next

    If files.Count > 1 Then                 'If files exist in dir, count them and get how many lists

        path = destination & "\" & name & version & ".txt"
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)        'creates the first text file
        fs.Close()
        passTexts.Add(path)

        For Each foundfile As String In files
            Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path)
                Console.WriteLine(foundfile)
                sw.WriteLine(foundfile)
            End Using
            infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundfile)
            total = total + infoReader.Length
            If total >= number Then                         'If max file size is reached
                version = Chr(Asc(version) + 1)                     'Increments Version
                path = destination & "\" & name & version & ".txt"      'Corrects path
                fs = File.Create(path)        'creates the new text file with updated path
                fs.Close()
                passTexts.Add(path)
                total = 0                   'resets total
            End If
        Next
    End If


    Return passTexts




End Function
```

Comment: What value are you actually passing in as number?

Comment: 10000000. It should be adding 150000 per file max

Comment: If I understand you, then you want to write the CONTENT of each file in just one file until this file reaches the maximum length of 10 MB? Are these file to be inserted in the big one all text files?

Comment: Thats weird it works fine when i try it. The only problem i had was occasionally getting an arithmetic overflow exception due to some of the files having a length greater than int.MaxValue, easily fixed by changing total to a Long. Would suggest you write the file size and cumulative total next to the filename to help you further

Comment: Each file will be a picture file; either jpg or something similar. I am taking the address of each file and adding it to a text file to be used later by Winzip. Each text file should contain a varying number of strings containing the addresses of these files. The size of the picture file is what determines the number of entries in the text file. For instance, if each file is 1 MB, there should be ten file names in each text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time through the loop, you open the file (using the StreamWriter) which *overwrites* the previous contents.  Your file will only ever have one filename inside it.  Instead of opening and writing every time through the loop, only write the file when you have accumulated all the filenames.  I removed the calls to File.Create as they aren't necessary.  The StreamWriter will create the file if it doesn't exist.  And I changed the ArrayList's to List(Of String) since they're easier to work with.  Also, be sure to turn Option Strict On.  This code has not been tested, but it should get my point across.  I hope I haven't misunderstood what you were trying to do.

```
Private Function GenerateListsForSize(source As String, destination As String, name As String, number As Integer) As List(Of String)
    Dim files As New List(Of String)()
    Dim filenamesToWrite As New List(Of String)()
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim version As Char = "A"
    Dim filename As String
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim passTexts As New List(Of String)()
    Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo

    files.AddRange(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(source))

    If files.Count > 1 Then                 'If files exist in dir, count them and get how many lists

        'Path.Combine is preferable to concatenating strings.
        filename = Path.Combine(destination, String.Format("{0}{1}.txt", name, version))
        passTexts.Add(filename)

        For Each foundfile As String In files
            filenamesToWrite.Add(foundfile)
            infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundfile)
            total = total + infoReader.Length
            If total >= number Then                         'If max file size is reached

                'Only write when the list is complete for this batch.
                Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(filename)
                    For Each fname As String In filenamesToWrite
                        Console.WriteLine(foundfile)
                        sw.WriteLine(foundfile)
                    Next
                End Using

                version = Chr(Asc(version) + 1)                     'Increments Version
                filename = Path.Combine(destination, String.Format("{0}{1}.txt", name, version)) 'corrects path
                passTexts.Add(filename)   'IS THIS A DUPLICATE????
                total = 0                  'resets total
                filenamesToWrite.Clear()  'clear the list of file names to write
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return passTexts

End Function
```